# Visual Studio 2015: WebTest Validate Response with Regex

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webtest

I'm try to use regex to validate response text in a webtest. With ValidationRuleFindText class, you have the option to use regex to validate response text from a web request. Example:

Response Text: {"success":true, "data":"foo bar"}

```
ValidationRuleFindText validationRule = new ValidationRuleFindText();
validationRule.FindText = @"/(/""success/"":true)/ig";
validationRule.IgnoreCase = true;
validationRule.UseRegularExpression = true;
validationRule.PassIfTextFound = true;
foobarRequest.ValidateResponse += new EventHandler<ValidationEventArgs>    (validationRule3.Validate);
```

For someone reason it's not recognizing that validationRule.FindText is regex and it fails because it literally can't find /(/"success/":true)/ig in the response. If anyone is familiar with this, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure it uses the JavaScript way of defining regular expressions? (the /<regex>/<flags>). Try removing the slashes and the flags (ig) at the end.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, i'll try removing the slashes and let you know if it works. I'm running a loadtest at the moment. Thank you for your suggest!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy to work out using Visual Studio. Take any `.webtest` file that can be used as a sandbox file. Add a find text validation rule with the correct settings and then run the "generate code" command. The correct code for the validation will be seen in the generated `.cs` file.

For the example string in the question, the search string `{"success":true, "data":"foo bar"}` generates the line below. The other validation rule lines are the same as in the question.

```
validationRule1.FindText = "{\"success\":true, \"data\":\"foo bar\"}";
```

Finally, there is nothing about this search string that needs a regular expression. A non-regular-expression validation rule would suffice.

---

The line in the question has `validationRule.FindText = @"/(/""success/"":true)/ig";` which appears to be appealing to the way regular expressions are used in some other languages. The enclosing `/` characters and the trailing `ig` should not be used. Their functionality is achieved by other means.

Comment: Thanks!! For the input :) I've got validation working now. I appreciate your help!